# SQL Joins giving wrong count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join

I have a query below written in non-ansi and I am converting into ansi for Migration from SQL 2008 to 2012. The problem is the count for below queries are not matching.

```
 Select  count(*) 
 FROM t1 ,t2 ,t3,t4,t5
 WHERE t3.RequestId = t1.GenRequestId
 AND t1.RequestType = 'xxx'
 AND t4.RequestId =* t3.RequestId
 AND t4.ItemTypeId =* t2.ItemTypeId 
 AND t1.managerid *= t5.managerid 

 Select  count(*)
 FROM t1
 LEFT JOIN t5 ON t1.managerid = t5.managerid,
 t4
 RIGHT JOIN t3 ON t4.RequestId = t3.RequestId
 RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t4.ItemTypeId = t2.ItemTypeId
 WHERE t3.RequestId = t1.GenRequestId
 AND t1.RequestType = 'xxx'
```

I want same count when using joins. Appreciate your help..!!

Comment: LEFT/RIGHT JOIN and INNER JOIN (t1,t2..) are not same.

Comment: The order of the join operations is relevant, if outer joins are involved. You cannot change them and expect the same result: first an inner join of t1 and t3, then aright join of t4 and t3, next right join t4 and t2 and last a left join of t1 and t5.

Comment: Adding to Ejay's comment - I also don't see a Join on t4 in your second query

Answer (score 1):

To approach this, rewrite the original so everything is a left outer join:

```
Select  count(*) 
 FROM t1 ,t2 ,t3,t4,t5
 WHERE t3.RequestId = t1.GenRequestId
 AND t1.RequestType = 'xxx'
 AND t3.RequestId *= t4.RequestId
 AND t2.ItemTypeId *= t4.ItemTypeId 
 AND t1.managerid *= t5.managerid ;
```

Then use the ordering suggested by this for the final query (tables on the left hand side need to appear before tables on the right hand side):

```
 SELECT  count(*)
 FROM t1 INNER JOIN
      t3
      ON t3.RequestId = t1.GenRequestId LEFT OUTER JOIN
      t4
      ON t3.RequestId = t4.RequestId LEFT OUTER JOIN
      t2
      ON t2.ItemTypeId = t4.ItemTypeId LEFT OUTER JOIN
      t5
      ON t1.managerid = t5.managerId;
 WHERE t1.RequestType = 'xxx';
```

To be honest, though, I find the old style join syntax very difficult to work with.  And, I find it really difficult to work with mixtures of `left outer join` and `right outer join`.  I'd be inclined to go back to the data and rewrite the query from scratch.

Comment: +1 - Generally, I find `OUTER JOIN`s to `OUTER JOIN`s to be unnecessary/misleading; Often the rows actually _do_ exist, or are required, or can be joined to the original table, or similar.  For instance, given the name `ItemTypeId`, whatever's being referenced as `t2` is likely a fact/type table.  I too would go back to the data and re-write.

Comment: @user2625377 . . . My advice in that case is to start with `select count(*) from t1` and add conditions in one at a time, using both formats, to see where the problem is and how to fix it.

Comment: Dear Gordon Linoff...The first format gives me the correct count but the second format gives me less count..